# PayPal Receipt not showing Description information using SetExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal's API to process a payment using SetExpressCheckout method.

```
$requestParams = array(
   'RETURNURL' => 'SUCCESS_PAGE_URL',
   'CANCELURL' => 'CANCE_PAGE_URL'
);

$orderParams = array(
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $price,
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => '0',
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => $price
);

$item = array(
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => $item_name,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => $item_description,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => $price,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1'
);

$paypal = new Paypal();
$response = $paypal -> request('SetExpressCheckout',$requestParams + $orderParams + $item);
```

It all works great, but even though the description is showing in the PayPal's checkout page, the email receipt that I get is missing the description information.

Does anyone know what how I can get the description to show on the receipt?

Comment: I'm really not sure why they provide that separate "DESC" field because I've never seen it show up anywhere.  I've always used the NAME for whatever detail I want to pass there.  Usually something like Name - Description, but passed in the name field only.

Comment: Neither one shows up in there though... I am submitting both L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 and L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0. You would think it would show something in there. It does show up in the checkout page, so I know it's going through, just not to the email receipt for some reason.

Comment: You need to make sure to send it in both SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Comment: Andrew, can you give an example of how I would do that? Do I do that within the same function or what do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: They are 2 separate calls in the flow.  SetExpressCheckout begins the process, and including itemized details there will show the details on the PayPal checkout page.  DoExpressCheckoutPayment is the final call in the flow and is very similar to SEC.  If you don't include all of the same details in DECP, though, they will not be included in the final PayPal transaction details.

Comment: Andrew, doing this will not charge the customer twice?

Comment: No.  No money is moved at all until the final DECP call is made, and the only details that are included in the PayPal transaction are what gets included at that point.

Comment: Guys, thank you for all the answers. I am still confused. Because using the code above, I get a response of "Success" and get a "TOKEN", at which point I call:

header( 'Location: https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . urlencode($token) );

And the transaction is complete. Money did get sent, but the description in the email receipt is blank.

I am sorry, but can someone show me an example of how all this would look together?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. When the SetExpressCheckout is done and returns "Success" it gets redirected to PayPal, after which it goes back to your specified RETURNURL. On this RETURNURL page, for DoExpressCheckoutPayment, you need to specify the order details, this is what shows up in the invoice. Here is the code:

```
 // Complete the checkout transaction
$requestParams = array(
   'TOKEN' => $_GET['token'],
   'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
   'PAYERID' => $_GET['PayerID'],
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '1', // Same amount as in the original request
   'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD' // Same currency as the original request
```

);

```
$item = array(
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => $name, 
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => $desc, // <-- this is the description
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => $price,
   'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1'
);

$response = $paypal -> request('DoExpressCheckoutPayment',$requestParams + $item);
```